# html file uploads and python cgi

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

I'm trying to upload files to my '/uploads' directory with [this guide](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/) using a python uploader instead of php (so I can do some renaming and fancy pre-processing in a language I understand).

So I have the template `index.html` and the form itself looks like:

```
<form id="upload" method="post" action="upload.py" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="drop">
                Drop Files Here

                <a>Browse</a>
                <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
            </div>

            <ul>
                <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
            </ul>
        </form>
```

and the python cgi script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi, os
import cgitb
import logging
try: # Windows needs stdio set for binary mode.
    import msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode(0, os.O_BINARY) # stdin  = 0
    msvcrt.setmode(1, os.O_BINARY) # stdout = 1
except ImportError:
    pass
cgitb.enable()
logging.basicConfig(filename='cgi.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.info('log created')

def fbuffer(f, chunk_size=10000):
    """Generator to buffer file chunks"""
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
        if not chunk: 
            break
        yield chunk

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# A nested FieldStorage instance holds the file
if 'file' in form:
    filefield = form['file']
    if not isinstance(filefield, list):
        filefield = [filefield]
else:
    logging.debug('no file found')

# Test if the file was uploaded
for fileitem in filefield:
    if fileitem.filename:
        fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename) # strip leading path from file name to avoid directory traversal attacks
        if fn.split('.')[-1].lower() in ['png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip']:
            with open('uploads/' + fn, 'wb', 10000) as f:
                # Read the file in chunks
                for chunk in fbuffer(fileitem.file):
                  f.write(chunk)
            print '{"status":"success"}'
        else:
            print '{"status": "error"}'

    else:
        print '{"status":"error"}'
```

However, nothing is written to 'uploads', a log is not created and `cgitb.enable()` doesn't do anything I can see! I have no idea where to go from here. How can I debug something that can't output anything?
The original php code I'm trying to emulate is:

```
<?php

// A list of permitted file extensions
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip');

if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
        echo '{"status":"error"}';
        exit;
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
        echo '{"status":"success"}';
        exit;
    }
}

echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
```

Comment: i think it has somethings to do with special character inside the file